Monte Carlo Integration and Importance Sampling: Seeking Clarification from Textbook
I was reading the book Realistic Ray-Tracing by Peter Shirley. On page 87, it is written:
For a function $f$ and a random variable $x \sim p$, we can approximate the expected value of $f(x)$ by a sum:
$E(f(x)) = \int_{x \in S} f(x) p(x) d\mu \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)$ (Eq. 11.4)
Because the expected value can be expressed as an integral, the integral is also approximated by the sum. The form of equation 11.4 is a bit awkward; we would usually like to approximate an integral of a single function ( g ) rather than a product ( fp ). We can get around this by substituting ( g = fp ) as the integrand:
$\int_{x \in S} g(x) d\mu \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{g(x_i)}{p(x_i)}$ (Eq. 11.5)
When I initially looked at the text, I got confused. I realized later that this might have been because the author uses both $p(x)$ in both equations but that in fact, these effectively refer to two different probability distributions, for which it would have been better to use two different names.

We have $g(x) = f(x)p(x)$, so we have a probability distribution here that is "specific" to the function for which we want to get an estimate. For example, a simple case would be one in which the random variable could either be 1 or 2, where the probability of getting a 2 is 0.8 and a 1 is 0.2. So the expected value would indeed be $1 \times 0.2 + 2 \times 0.8 $.

We have cases where the probability distribution $p(x)$ can't be sampled analytically or is not even known. For instance, we could know the probability of $x=2$ is greater than that of $x=1$, but we wouldn't know what these probabilities are exactly. Therefore, when using the Monte Carlo method to get an approximation, we could in this case use importance sampling: for that, we would choose a probability distribution, say $q(x)$, which would have a "shape" similar to that of $p(x)$. We choose $q(x)$ because we can draw samples from that probability distribution whereas we couldn't with $p(x)$ (or we could do so more easily). But to account for the potential bias or skew induced by using this probability distribution, we need to divide the $g(x_i)$ by $q(x_i)$.


$\int_{x \in S} g(x) d\mu \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{g(x_i)}{q(x_i)}$ (Eq. 11.5)
So, I think where the book is potentially misleading is that the probability distribution in the denominator of equation 11.5 is called $p(x)$ where, for clarity, it would have been better to call it something else, like $q(x)$—as I did. The way it is done in the book might mislead the reader to think that this $p(x)$ is the same as the one used in equation 11.4. But they are different, yes?
Am I correct? Or did I get this wrong?
